# Use Wrapbootstrap theme with Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to use a WrapBootstrapTheme with Aurelia-js and I have difficulties.
I use Aurelia CLI bundler with requirejs and Typescript.

I have added the theme script (app.min.js) into the index.html file like this:

```
<body>
    <!-- begin #page-loader -->
    <div id="page-loader" class="fade show">
        <span class="spinner"></span>
    </div>
    <!-- end #page-loader -->

    <div id="page-container" aurelia-app="main" class="fade page-sidebar-fixed page-header-fixed gradient-enabled">        
    </div>
</body>
<script src="/scripts/app.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/vendor-bundle.js" data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper"></script>
```

Everything work fine and the theme script works, aurelia binding works.
But if I try to use JQuery, by importing it into main.ts I am getting an error:

```
app.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function
at handleDraggablePanel (app.min.js:1)
at Object.initComponent (app.min.js:1)
at Object.init (app.min.js:1)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.min.js:1)
at t (app.min.js:1)
at e (app.min.js:1)
```

I know that Jquery, Jquery-ui and bootstrap are included in the theme script.

How can I make this to work?

Thanks

**Update**
@bigopon
The theme has 1 script "app.min.js". I have included this script in the Index.html like i wrote above. Then I tried to use aurelia-jstree plugin. After I included the plugin in the main.ts file, the error ($(...).sortable is not a function) appeared. Then I noticed that whenever I use a plugin or anything that uses jquery or including jquery itself in the app.ts or main.tss or any .ts file, i get the same error.
I saw that the theme script "app.min.js" has jquery and jquery-ui-dist included in it. So the problem seem the order of script execution. Where the jquery and jquery-ui-dist in the theme script executes first, and the jquery that I include in Aurelia app executes at a latter time and overrides the first one.

Now I tried to include the theme source script without the jquery and jquery-ui-dist in it. I also got the same error. Maybe my configuration in aurelia project json file is wrong. I don't know how to include the theme script with all dependencies and that works. I even tried to set shim = true but with no success.

I've made a tst repo on gitlab: [test app](https://gitlab.com/l.cetina/aurelia-test)

**Update 2**
@huocp
Thanks for the response, but...
I went with the second option, of removing jquery in the build process.
I left the include "jquery" in the main.ts. Now I get new error:
[image]

I have updated the repo with the change. Why I went with the second one, because I know that sometimes in the future I will be required to use jquery. Also I use typescript so I must import the modules else I get compile errors.
I have also the theme script without the jquery ini it (also in the repo) but then I don't know how to configure aurelia so the script keeps working by using the jquery and jquery ui from the vendors bundle.

Comment: This probably means the order is wrong. How do you incldue those scripts at the moment?

Comment: I added an update section

Comment: I think you could levergage the shim configuration. I'll ping Chungpeng Huo for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `src/main.ts` has `import "jquery"` which causes cli-bundler to pack jquery into `vendor-bundle.js`.

You don't want that jquery, because the theme js already provided jquery.

The solution is simple, just remove `import "jquery"` from `src/main.ts`.

Note you might want to use other jquery plugins in your app, when you do `import "jquery-foo";`, that plugin will likely depend on jquery which will cause cli-bundler to pack jquery into `vendor-bundle.js` again.

To prevent jquery from packed into vendor bundle. You have two options:

1. never do `import foo from "jquery-foo"`, but use `aurelia.json` prepend for all jquery plugins. Like:

```
"prepend": [
  // don't prepend jquery here because them had it!
  // prepend all jquery plugins
  "node_modules/jquery-foo/to/main/file.js",
  "node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js",
  "node_modules/promise-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js",
  "node_modules/requirejs/require.js"
],
```

2. use `import foo from "jquery-foo"`, you can even use `import "jquery"`, then modify your `tasks/build.ts`.

```js
  function writeBundles() {
    return buildCLI.dest({
      onRequiringModule: function(moduleId) {
        // This prevents cli-bundler from packing jquery
        // into vendor-bundle, just return global var $
        // which is created by your theme js.
        if (moduleId === 'jquery') return 'define(function(){return $;});';
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I added "update 2" section with the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I think I missed something. Try `if (moduleId === 'jquery') return 'define(function(){return $;});';`. I am away from computer, let me know if it works, I will update answer after.

Comment: With this modification, IT WORKS! Thanks a lot.